# Sending and receiving sms in backend of iPhone

Tags: iphone, sms

I am new to iPhone application development. In the application that I am developing for iPhone there is a module which sends the sms without knowing to the user to my sms server and gets the response and displays the result. Is there any way to send and receive sms message in app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with the iPhone SDK as it stands. It's probably not possible with any mobile platform without the user knowing about it as it's an obvious security hole.

Comment: It's certainly possible in Windows Mobile.

Comment: @Steve Weet wow. Is there no opt-in when you first run the app or anything?

Comment: I don't believe so. I'm working on a project at the moment that sends location based data via SMS (If Gprs/WiFi is not available) and it does this silently in the background.

Comment: Its possible in many J2ME, BlackBerry and Windows Mobile. Any one has doubt on this try my company app http://shorthandmobile.in/

Comment: @Steve Weet how can we do so? Please can you give us some information about it?

Comment: It's possible on Android. The user has to opt in at installation time (same as all other permissions).

Answer (score 1):

You should use data instead of SMS.

SMS are not a way to send information between a client and a server, but Internet is. And by using data, you also get a much more reliable transfer protocol (SMS aren't).

You shouldn't send SMS without the agreement of your users, because it can become really costly. Imagine you have a user on vacation in another country, and think that your app is using wifi, while it is using SMS. This user will be really mad when he will get is cellphone bill.

So even if you can do it, I think you shouldn't. And if you really need to do this, be sure that it is really clear to the user that your app is going to send SMS from his phone (with the charge of a normal SMS).

Comment: There are many devices which can (only) be controlled via SMS messages. Creating a user friendly interface to handle such messages on a smartphone (that already has SMS capability) is a very real use case.

Comment: Apple doesn't allow developers to send SMS from their app because it can become a big problem for users. Imagine an app where it is not clear that it's actually sending SMS instead of using data. Every SMS could nearly cost 1$ when you are on roaming. I know Android let you do this, but I think that it's really dangerous. And if you really need to send SMS, you can still connect your App to a server (using data) that will do it for you.

Comment: Yes, there is room for abuse and I understand why Apple doesn't allow them. I also agree with you that SMS _should not be_ a way to send information between a client and a server. Unfortunately there are zillions of devices (security panels, gate controls, home automation) already installed out there that can only be controlled with SMS. The inability to couple SMS control with a graphic interface on a device which would otherwise be able to do both causes unending headaches to many developers, which is why this question pops up so often.

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on GPS-based application and I can have the device stop sending SMS back to the user every time the user send an SMS command. I think as long as the SMS is sent, it should be fine.

If the user wants to see the status of the device, then I might have to establish communication between my server and the device via TCP/UDP and have the iPhone app "parse" the information and display the status. Perhaps the best way is to have the server respond to the iPhone app saying "The device received your SMS command" and display it on the app so that the user knows his/her SMS were sent.

But yes, if we could get the location via SMS, then I could send those coordinates to the Google Maps app in the iPhone itself and it would display it for you.

Comment: How to send SMS from iphone app without opening the SMS interface? Can you please tell us something about that?

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of an App on Android which does this, called [ImHerePlus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paulxiong.imhereplus). Check it out and see if it helps.